# NSDate is returning null on certain dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am iterating through a for loop and getting my dates as strings from a json string. What is happening is, I am trying to convert each date string to a NSDate. The issue I am having is every time the dates starts with something other than 08 i.e 09-13-2014, i keep getting null returned. I have changed the dates on my server and tested the dates and as long as the date starts with 08 i.e. 08-31-2014 it works perfect. Any ideas?

```
 NSString *myDate = item[@"stringdate"];
    NSString *yourDate = item[@"sswStringDate"];
    NSLog(@"thedate %@", myDate);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *dateFromString;
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY"];

    NSString *stringFromDate  = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
    NSLog(@"sst %@", stringFromDate);
```

My log statements is

```
thedate 08-31-2014 
 sst 08-31-2014 
 thedate 08-20-2015 
 sst 08-20-2014
 thedate 11-31-2014 
 sst (null) 
 thedate 09-31-2014 
 sst (null) 
 thedate 08-31-2014 
 sst 08-31-2014
```

Comment: Last I checked, November and September only have 30 days.

Comment: 30 days has September, April, June and November, all the rest have 31 except for February because it's dumb.

Comment: OMG!!! How could I not see that!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dates 11/31 and 9/31 don't exist.